# Check for condition in consecutive cells within whole column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a excel column containing rainfall data (amount of rainfall) for a given month.
I want to check for the first day of a specific sub-timeframe (e.g. Day 1 - 10 of a 30 Day timeframe) where the following conditions are met:

Sum of rainfall on Day x + the following 4 days is 10 units or higher. 
Two of the five days have to have at least 3 or more units of rainfall.

*Further conditions for the next task:
If the rainfall-sum of the consecutive days in the specific sub-timeframe (Day 1 - 10) is always zero, continue checking in the next timeframe (Day 11 - 20).
If the rainfall-sum of the consecutive days in the specific sub-timeframe (Day 1 - 10) is >0 but never reached 10, return the last day of the sub-timeframe.*

If the conditions are met, I want the formula to return the value of the last of the consecutive cells + 1. I thought about something like this:

```
=IF(SUM('Rainfall Data'!A1:A5)>10,A2,"false")
...
=IF(SUM('Rainfall Data'!A10:A15)>10,A11,"false")
```

However, how would I include the second criteria (2 Cells have to be at least 3 units) into a formula like this? Is Excel even a suitable solution for this or would something like R-Studio or VBA be more appropriate? Especially if looking at the further criteria I want to take into consideration later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include the second criteria *2 Cells have to be at least 3 units* you can simply add another IF for when the first criteria returns true.
Then, to check whether at least two of the cells are at least 3 or more, you can use the `COUNTIF` function.
So within the previous "true" we add If(Countif(range,criteria)>=2,A2,False)
Like so:

```
=IF(SUM('Rainfall Data'!A1:A5)>10,IF(COUNTIF('Rainfall Data'!A1:A5,">=3")>=2,A2,"false"),"false")
```

If you want to add a lot more conditions it can become a bit hard to work with, and then VBA might be easier.